# Magento transaction email css not loading properly

Tags: css, email, magento, templates, transactions

I have created one custom email template for cancel order. Email working fine. Template header, footer also coming in email template but existing css not coming in email template. I have used default header & footer, for others transaction email everything working fine except my custom email. But when I checked the email preview from admin section , its showing fine as well. Please suggest me how to fix the issue.

Comment: It could be useful for you: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Likely it is because you need to inline your stylesheet. Some email clients will completely strip the head and style tag while others have limited support.

To check on what CSS is accepted in which client check [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css).

This is a good [inliner tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)